Shopware use tailwind.css @apply - don't work
I was trying to use a tailwind theme in shopware but i can't make it work because i think the @apply isn't reconized. The theme is Cartzio (no longer available https://themeforest.net/item/cartzio-ecommerce-tailwind-css-template/50099131), does anyone use tailwind themes in shopware or does know how to make it work?
Thanks in advance for any help. Best Regards.
